# SQL Query Performence is too bad for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-tuning

I run the following SQL Query on a MySQL platform.

Table A is a table which has a single column (primary key) and 25K rows. 
Table B has several columns and 75K rows.

It takes 20 minutes to execute following query. I will be glad if you could help.

```
INSERT INTO sometable
SELECT A.PrimaryKeyColumn as keyword, 'SomeText', B.*
FROM A, B
WHERE B.PrimaryKeyColumn = CONCAT(A.PrimaryKeyColumn, B.NotUniqueButIndexedColumn);
```

Comment: I think the Concat() function removes the benefits of the indexes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the `SELECT` without the `INSERT` to see if the problem is with the `SELECT` or not.

If it is with the `SELECT`, follow [the MySQL documentation explaining how to optimize queries using `EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html).

If the `SELECT` runs fine but the `INSERT` takes forever, make sure you don't have a lot of unnecessary indexes on `sometable`.  Beyond that, you may need to do some MySQL tuning and/or OS tuning (e.g., memory or disk performance) to get a measurable performance boost with the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you are roughly trying to insert 1.875 Billion records - (which does not match the where clause).

For that 20 minutes doesn't sound too bad....